# Android mediacodec: Is it possible to encode audio and video at the same time using mediacodec and muxer?

Tags: android, mediamuxer, android-mediacodec

There is some good documentation on [this](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) site called big flake about how to use media muxer and mediacodec to encode then decode video as mp4, or extract video then encode it again and more stuff.

But it doesnt seem that there is a way to encode audio with video at the same time, no documentation or code about this. It doesn't seem impossible.

**Question**

Do you know any stable way of doing it that will work on all devices greater than android 18?

Why no one implemented it, is it hard to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create 2 Mediacodec instances, one for video and one for audio and then use MediaMuxer to mux the video with audio after encoding, you can take a look at [ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java) and at [this project to capture camera/mic and save to mp4 file using Mediamuxer and Mediacodec](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/serenegiant/encoder/)

Comment: this link shows you how to extract audio and video and then mux them, but the question is from where do i get the audio when I am encoding the video, plus is this a stable way?

Comment: Probabelly you will get your audio as RAW data from a source (Phone mic for example), and yes it is the most stable way to do it, see my edit (https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/serenegiant/encoder/MediaAudioEncoder.java)

Comment: Lets say that I encoded a video in a way such that I - frames are 1 sec away or 2 sec away from each other, does this affect the end video when audio is also muxed?

Comment: or audio and video formats are independent of each other?

Comment: audio and video format are independant because you use 2 mediacodec instances, but you have to sync the audio with the video returned the encoders (how many audio samples must play for each video frame)

Comment: I wanted to ask you what is meant by (track) in terms of media muxer it confuses me, and does it mean that each audio and video are added to same track?

Comment: MP4 (and others format) is a container wich can contain different type of data (metadata, audio, video) called tracks, so a track can be a video data, audio data or metadata (ex : gyro infos)

Comment: so when muxing video and audio I add them as 2 different tracks?

Comment: if yes then how do they exactly sync?

Comment: please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972049/how-to-provide-both-audio-data-and-video-data-to-mediamux

Comment: I tried to record video and audio seperately at same time and then mixed them together is it safe or bad idea.

Comment: Yes, it is the safe idea, the question is how to sync them, please take a look at the link above

Comment: No I meant record the video alone to a file and then the audio alone to a file, and then get both files and merge them together using media extractor .....is it bad or safe?

Comment: It is possible to do that with mediacodec, you can use extractor if you muxed audio and video files before (each one in a .mp4) and then mux them together or just mediamuxer if you saved the files without muxing before (e.g : video .h264/.264, audio .aac/3gp)

Comment: ahh okay ...do you by any chance know anything about mediaprojection?

Comment: If you want to capture the device screen, you can follow this example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture (without using mediacodec) or this one https://github.com/saki4510t/ScreenRecordingSample (using mediacodec)

Comment: yeah exactly, I want to ask you about this issue, what is the recommended way using media recorder or mediacodec to use mediaprojection? what is your advice?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, MediaRecorder is (easier) a high level Interface. But you cannot process frames because they aren't accessible for example, with MediaCodec you can do what you want with frames because you can manipulate the codec buffers, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248199/mediacodec-vs-mediaplayer-and-mediarecorder?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa and here http://www.hnwatcher.com/r/1170899/Video-recording-and-processing-in-Android

Comment: Excuse me if I am asking too much, I am trying to learn from you as you are an expert in media stuff. You mean by processing frames that we can edit them or delete them or crop them when we use mediacodec but not when we use mediarecorder.....plus has anyone added audio while using media projection in mediacodec?

Comment: OH no I am not an expert, just in this moment I deal a lot with mediacodec API. So yes, with mediarecorder you cannot modify frames directly, with mediacodec you can. And yes, as I said before, with mediamuxer you can added audio track to a video track recorder by mediacodec through mediaprojection virtual display surface